# Flutter app: fetch data from sqlite frequently or store in memory

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have a flutter app that has some master data and 2 bigger tables with parent child relation. The data is stored on the device in SQLite database. I expect hundreds or maybe a couple thousand records in the biggest table, which is the child table. From these records I create lists of objects.
In the app I need these lists ordered by different fields. For me it seems much easier to fetch the data from the database every time I need it.

My question is, which is the better approach?

- Fetching the entire database when the app is opening and working with these lists in memory. For me the downside of this solution is that I need to maintain the order of the lists which can be quite painful compared to a single SQL statement. The order of the objects in those lists are quite important!
- Or should I read the data from the database every time when I need it? And this means that I read only those records from the DB that I need for a given screen.

Which is the better approach from performance point of view?

Answer (score 0):

Unless its forn an MVP with too little data then approach two.
It will be a little more cumbersome for you to implement but it will make the app more future proof and not waste loads of RAM(if the device does have enough).
You'll probably would have to implement paginated requests(selects, with limit and offset) While the user scrolls and reset those if the filters change.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, paging is best choice for performance.

If you more optimize. Caching what has already been loaded, next page preload when scroll down